# change the content of a window control template in WPF

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I have an application with multiple windows (as dialogs), most of them have the same controls (an expander on the left, and a datagrid on the right).

What is the best way to develop such application? I thought about writing a control template for the window like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="WindowControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.20*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.80*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Expander ExpandDirection="Right" IsExpanded="True" Grid.Column="0">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="Control Panel" Background="Gray">
                        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Expander.Header>
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFBFB5B5" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFC97A7A" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Grid.Background>
                </Grid>
            </Expander>

            <DataGrid Grid.Column="2">
            </DataGrid>

        </Grid>
    </Border>

</ControlTemplate>
```

I then define a new window with this template, but I don't know how to add controls to the expander and how to bind data to the datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple if I put it this way:

1. You don't need multiple windows or multiple controls to achieve this.
2. Just create 1 window with all required parts in it.
3. Write your `DataTemplate`s inside the `Resources` of each of these parts.
4. If you do it as described below, the different parts of your View can find the correct templates.

In this approach, DataTemplates which are used in Resources of Expander or ContentPresenter are being automatically chosen and set according to the correct type of `DataContext`. Notice that I had to eliminate `x:Key` from these DataTemplates and from Style which is used to set common properties of datagrids.

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="0.20*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="0.80*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <Expander ExpandDirection="Right" IsExpanded="True" Grid.Column="0">
         <Expander.Resources>
             <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyType1}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFBFB5B5" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFC97A7A" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Grid.Background>
                </Grid>
             </DataTemplate>
             <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyType2}">
                 <Grid>
                     <Grid.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FAAA" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#F0F0" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                     </Grid.Background>
                 </Grid>
             </DataTemplate>
         </Expander.Resources>

         <Expander.Header> 
             <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="Control Panel" Background="Gray">
                  <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                      <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                  </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
             </TextBlock>
         </Expander.Header>

         <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
     </Expander>

     <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
         <ContentPresenter.Resources>
             <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyType1}">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList1}">
                   <DataGrid.Columns>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyProperty1}"/>
                   </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
             </DataTemplate>

             <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyType2}">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList2}">
                   <DataGrid.Columns>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyProperty2}"/>
                   </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
             </DataTemplate>
         </ContentPresenter.Resources>
     </ContentPresenter>
</Grid>
```

In this example I used 2 view models named MyType1 (having a list named MyList1 that each element is view model itself and has a property named MyProperty1) and MyType2 (same as MyType1 but with MyList2 and MyProperty2)

You can open a Window like below:

```
Window w1 = new Window();
w1.DataContext = new MyType1();
w1.Show();
```

### note:

additionally in order to avoid redundancy in DataGrid's code, you can add a Style to `ContentPresenter.Resources` with no `x:Key` to set some properties for `DataGrid`. these properties will be applied to any `DataGrid` which is a in part of that `ContentPresenter`.

```
     <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
         <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
            </Style>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyType1}">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList1}">
                ...
             ...
          ...
```

### note:

wrong code:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Setter Property="DataGrid.Columns">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
```

The reason that I didn't use the above code for generalizing the DataGrid is that DataGrid.Columns is an attached property and can't be set in style's setter. but if datagrid columns in all dialogs are the same you can use a simpler approach for datagrid.

this way you have to have a common name for the list and its elements' properties:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCommonList}">
       <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyCommonProperty}"/>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Although this works. It is  completely superfluous. ContentPresenter will already search the resources for a datatemplate with the correct DataType tag.

Comment: This method ensures that even if two templates for one data type exist, the right template is chosen. since the infrastructure is available one can simply add the desired logic to templateSelector's code and make it more customizable.

Comment: But you're right I added a comment to highlight the purpose of template selector in this scenario.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand the answer. I want to use my template to create more than 10 windows (dialog), and inside each one I need to add some controls to the expander, and to bind the grid to some data.

Comment: Sorry to respond too late. take a look at the changed answer please.